# Bar chart with d3.js and an associative array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, associative-array, bar-chart

I give up, I can't figure it out.
I was trying to create a bar chart with `3d.js` but I can't get it working. Probably I don't understand it enough to deal with my complicate associative array.

My array has the following structure:

```
{"January"=>{"fail"=>13, "success"=>6},  
 "February"=>{"success"=>10, "fail"=>4},  
 "March"=>{"success"=>9, "fail"=>13},  
 "April"=>{"success"=>16, "fail"=>5},   
 "May"=>{"fail"=>52, "success"=>23},   
 "June"=>{"fail"=>7, "success"=>2},   
 "July"=>{},  
 "August"=>{"fail"=>6, "success"=>3},  
 "September"=>{"success"=>54, "fail"=>59},   
 "October"=>{"success"=>48, "fail"=>78},  
 "November"=>{"fail"=>4, "success"=>6},  
 "December"=>{"fail"=>1, "success"=>0}}`
```

I got the displaying of the axis working: 
[image]

The code looks really ugly because I converted the names to a "normal" array:

```
monthsNames = new Array();
i = 0;
for (key in data) {
  monthsNames[i] = key;
  i++;
}

x.domain(monthsNames);
y.domain([0, 100]);
```

But I can't figure it out how to deal with the data.

I tried things like, `svg.selectAll(".bar").data(d3.entries(data))`
What is a good beginning I guess but I can't get the connection to the axis working.

What I want to create is a `bar-chart` that has the months as x-axis and every month has two bars (respectively one bar with two colours) - one for success and one for fail.

Can anybody please help me how to handle the data? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I cannot figure out how to scale x and y. If I use this code:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(monthsNames)
   .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0,100])
   .range([0, height]);
```

nothing is shown up then. If I print out the values that evaluate after using e.g. x(d.key) or x(d.value.fail) they are really strange numbers, sometimes even NaN.

EDIT:

```
d3.selectAll(".barsuccess")
      .on('mouseover', function(d){
                    svg.append('text')
                    .attr("x", x(d.key))
                    .attr("y", y(d.value.success))
                    .text(d.value.success+"%")
                    .attr('class','success')
                    .style("font-size","0.7em")
                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d){
                    d3.selectAll(".success").remove()
                });  


d3.selectAll(".barfail")
          .on('mouseover', function(d){
                        svg.append('text')
                        .attr("x", x(d.key)+x.rangeBand()/2)
                        .attr("y", y(d.value.fail))
                        .text(d.value.fail+"%")
                        .attr('class','fail')
                        .style("font-size","0.7em")
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function(d){
                        d3.selectAll(".fail").remove()
                    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to check out the bar chart tutorials [here](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html) and [here](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html). You have basically all you need already. The connection between the axes and the data are the functions that map input values (e.g. "March") to output coordinates (e.g. 125). You (presumably) created these functions using `d3.scale.*`. Now all you need to do is use the same functions to map your data to coordinates in the SVG.

The basic structure of the code you need to add looks like

```
svg.selectAll(".barfail").data(d3.entries(data))
   .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "barfail")
   .attr("x", function(d) { x(d.key) })
   .attr("width", 10)
   .attr("y", function(d) { y(d.value.fail) })
   .attr("height", function(d) { y(d.value.fail) });
```

and similar for `success`. If you use the same scale for the x axis for both types of bar, add a constant offset to one of them so the bars don't overlap. Colours etc can be set in the CSS classes.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and I read the tutorials. Even if I do not pay attention to the axis I cannot figure out how to scale x and y. I append that part to my code - would you be so kind to have a look at this?

Comment: ohweee, they could nothing be shown up because you do not use the "return" in your functions.

Comment: If you post your code somewhere where I can have a look (jsfiddle) I'd be happy to have a look.

Comment: Finally I got everything working besides the text. http://jsfiddle.net/pNcA6/ If I do it like this, it creates a HTML Text element inside the rect and obviously that is not working. But where else do I have to append the text then?

Comment: Sorry, the jsfiddle isn't working for me. It just gives me an error message.

Comment: I get something to work. I appended the code to my question. But I just get it working on hover.

Comment: I'm sorry it's still not working for me. It looks like you only have Javascript in there, no HTML and no external resources (i.e. d3). How are you testing your code?

Comment: oh sorry, I never used jsfiddle. I use the code in a ruby on rails project.

Comment: Here's [an introduction to jsfiddle](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html).